# is there any defect by increasing the data type size?

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

at the time of creating table we created one table with small int data type now, according to our requirement we have to increase the data type size or we have to change the data type from samll int to int.
this data type is used in somany proocedures and also given reference to another table.

now by increasing / changing the data type , is there any defect or not?
if any effects are there then how can i overcome it.

Comment: `is there any defect or not?` - what does that mean?

Answer (score 0):

in this situation, no there is no impact on existing data:  as long as you are moving up in data sizes (i.e. from smallint to int, varchar(50) to varchar(100), etc).

see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190273.aspx#alter_column

Comment: if we are using that column in stored procedure then we have to change it there also or not required to change

Comment: You shouldn't need to alter your stored procedure, but just to check, you can right-click in object explorer and choose 'script stored procedure as'-> 'Alter to' -> 'New query window'. Hit F5 (this won't actually run the procedure, but it will recompile it. If you come across any conversion errors it will tell you. If you get 'Command(s) completed successfully.' then there is nothing to do.

Comment: Hi twoleggedhorse , i followed according to you , right now my sp's are working fine . is there any defect in future i.e if data is increasing in table